# Drupal Auto-Change Path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, organic-groups

In my Drupal 7 site, I have a URL pattern set for new blog posts of `[node:og-group-ref:url:path]/blog/[node:title]`.

I want to create a rule for one organic group that when new posts are saved for that OG, there is a rule set that the path would automatically change to `[node:og-group-ref:url:path]/archive/[node:title]`.

Any ideas on how to do that within the Rules module?

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer your exact question. You CAN do it with the rules module.

Enable the rule module,

1. Create a new rule
2. Set "React on event" to "after saving new content" under the node heading.
3. (optional) 
   If you need it to match certain requirements, you could put a condition to check the values of certain token-exposed data.
4. Select "Add action", and on the next screen select "create or delete a path's url alias".

Construct the url alias at the bottom, using replacement patterns per your original answer.

You will be able to accomplish what you asked following this methodology.

Without knowing the exact specifics of the use case, there's also a chance you can do what you're looking to do with Pathauto alone

Comment: Thanks @Karl Buys!

However, I cannot get the orginal path to delete.

There is a pathauto set for the blog post content type. However, I want to create a rule to override it.

Any thoughts on what the rule conditions should be?

Comment: Hi @tcam27. Why not just use your original path you pasted in your post? Also, you're not easily going to be able to recreate the logic you described using pathauto, unless you define two separate content types, and change the path for each. Using pathauto, every single node of a specific content type will follow that single path you define